# Textures size libgdx

Tags: resize, libgdx, size, textures, screen-resolution

I have a game that involves a lot of textures. Now, when I debug my game on the desktop, the images and textures look fine. But when I run my game on my Samsung Galaxy S4, suddently the textures look very small.

My question is - how can I maintain the textures' size so they would look pretty much the same in all android devices?

Comment: Read up on Viewports: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: I have read this before but I don't see how it may help with my problem?

Comment: Can you link to screenshots of desktop and S4 versions so I can understand the issue better? Also post your code where you set up your camera and your `resize` method.